# RecyclerView insert animation breaks OnClick

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` and new items appear in it only at the top of the list. I want to use default insert animation for this action, but it breaks `OnClick()` method inside `ViewHolder`.
If I have inserted new item, `OnClick()` uses data from the previous item of ArrayList. If I use `NotifyDataSetChanged()`, data is ok, but of course, there is no animation. Looks like there is problem with `ViewHolder.bind()` method being not called. How can I update index of every item after `NotifyItemInserted(0)`?

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Song> data = new ArrayList<>();
//то, что ниже - для анимации
private static final int UNSELECTED = -1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private int selectedItem = UNSELECTED;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> data, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

public void insert(Song song)
{
    data.add(0, song);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}

public void swap(ArrayList<Song> datas){
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(datas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tv_songName;
    TextView tv_songGenreID;
    TextView tv_songUserInfo;
    ExpandableLayout expandableLayout;
    private CardView expandButton;
    private int position;
    private TextView youtubeButton;
    private TextView shareButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_songName);
        tv_songGenreID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_songGenreID);
        tv_songUserInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_songUserInfo);
        youtubeButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_button);
        shareButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        expandableLayout = (ExpandableLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
        expandableLayout.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        expandButton = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        expandButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        youtubeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bind(int position) {
        this.position = position;
        Song current = data.get(position);
        StringBuilder songInfo = new StringBuilder();
        songInfo.append(context.getString(R.string.genre));
        songInfo.append(current.songGenreID);
        songInfo.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        songInfo.append(context.getString(R.string.album));
        this.tv_songName.setText(current.songName);
        this.tv_songGenreID.setText(songInfo);
        this.tv_songUserInfo.setText(current.songUserInfo);
        expandButton.setSelected(false);
        expandableLayout.collapse(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.youtube_button:
                String youtubeURL = data.get(position).songName.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + youtubeURL;
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(youtubeURL));
                    context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.share_button:
                String songName = data.get(position).songName;
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, songName);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
                break;
            default:
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selectedItem);
                if (holder != null) {
                    holder.expandButton.setSelected(false);
                    holder.expandableLayout.collapse();
                }

                if (position == selectedItem) {
                    selectedItem = UNSELECTED;
                } else {
                    expandButton.setSelected(true);
                    expandableLayout.expand();
                    selectedItem = position;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
    setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
}

private int lastPosition = -1;

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(anim);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
}
```

**OnCreate() of Activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    layout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinator1);
    FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerViewEmptySupport) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.list_empty));
    myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AddSongDialogFragment addSongDialogFragment = new AddSongDialogFragment();
            addSongDialogFragment.show(fm, "add_song");
        }
    });
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, mRecyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    mAdapter.swap(dbHelper.readFromDB());
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setAddDuration(700);
    itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
}
```

Comment: try using `getAdapterPosition()`, it will give you the correct position every time, no need to complicate.

Comment: @Belzebub it helped me, thanks. Can you make an answer to this question for everyone instead of just comment? Almost every tutorial about animating RecyclerView uses this "position" variable, where simple getAdapterPosition can be used.

Comment: is it too late already?

Comment: @Belzebub of course not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()%22getAdapterPosition()) to get correct position of your item from your VIewHolder. That way the positions will not be mixed up after moving/deleting items from the RecyclerView.

NOTE: If the user clicks on the empty space during the animation`getAdapterPosition()` might return -1: make sure to handle the case.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());` to notify the other items after you added the new item.

You can also animate the `swap()` function if you use the functions `notifyItemRemoved()` `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyItemMoved()` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You only have to check if the new list includes the items of the old list.